# PHP money format with spaces

Tags: php, money-format

I am wondering if there is a way to separate thousands with space character.

For example:

```
$number = 21234.56;
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.utf8');
echo money_format('%i', $number);
```

is giving me:

```
21.234,56 PLN
```

And I want:

```
21 234,56 PLN
```

I don't want to make str_replace. I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`number-format`](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). For example :

```
echo number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
```

But you will have to put the unit yourself.

Otherwise, this [comment](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060) of the `money_format` documentation page gives a version of the function with some code that you can modify to change the thousand separator.

You can also do something like this :

```
$locale = localeconv();
$text = money_format('%i', $number);
$text = str_replace($locale['mon_thousands_sep'], ' ', $text);
```

Answer (score 7):

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

**`string number_format  ( float $number  , int $decimals = 0  , string $dec_point = '.'  , string $thousands_sep = ','  )`**

For your case:

```
number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
```